# DD-WRT Host IIS website

Tags: iis, networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a D-Link DIR-601 router.  I just swapped out the firmware for DD-WRT v24-sp2.

1) I used to have one of the computers on my network hosting an IIS 5 website on XP Pro.  After switching the firmware I am really struggling to find the steps to simply setup the website again for the internet.  I don't plan on hosting the site for the web on port 80 nor on the local computer on port 80.

2)  It seems that wireless is now weaker from the default settings with the combination of this router and DD-WRT.  I am no longer able to get enough of a signal to access the internet from a point in the house that used to run fine.  Again, if anyone could give me some optimal settings here, it would be great.

I have searched the internet, and I am really struggling to find anything useful in my situation.  Networking is certainly not my strong point.  I really appreciate your thorough guidance with this.

UPDATE:  I can access this site on my network just fine.  This site is ready to go.  The only variable is the router firmware, since this router worked fine before the switch-over to host the site.    to CGA, I am able to confirm that I am working in the right section of the router, and what I have been doing should be working.

Comment: You didn't mention how you're testing whether the web site is working from the Internet. I'll assume that when you say you can access the site from your network, you mean using the server's LAN IP (eg 192.168.xxx.xxx). If you try to access the site via your network's WAN IP (or the site's domain name, presumably) from a computer on your LAN, it won't work because DD-WRT doesn't enable NAT filtering by default (at least it didn't for me). Assuming I'm onto something here, what happens when you try to access the site from elsewhere on the Internet? If it works, then the problem is NAT filtering.

Comment: I am not able to access the site from without...  from the WAN address.  I tried accessing my WAN IP address from work today to no avail.  This used to work perfectly with the default router.  I have tried turning off windows firewall as well as the firmware firewall.

Comment: i checked a port checking site on the web.. the port xxxx is open for my external ip while all of the ports around it are closed, as expected.  I am totally at a loss as to why this is not forwarding.  I AM able to access the site perfectly fine form within the network using the internal ip address, 192.168.1.100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings for port forwarding are found here under the NAT/Qos tab under "Port forwarding". Just enter a description under "Application" and the port you want to use under "Port from" and "Port to". Set "Protocol" to TCP and "IP address" to the address of the computer you're hosting the web site on (the address on the local network, not the external address). Finally check "Enable".

Regarding you're wireless reception you could try to ramp up the transmission power. The setting is under the Wireless tab, advanced settings, look for the entry "Tx power". I don't have any recommendation on the setting for your specific router but generally it's best to increase in small steps and be aware that raising too high can burn out the wifi chipset. If you do it you're doing it at your own risk!!!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!  I have port forwarding modified in NAT/Qos.  I will remove my entries from "Port Range Forwarding".  I have not gotten it working with this configured.  Can you think of any other setting that might be required to ensure a site is live on the internet in addition to forwarding where you have directed me?  I have performed all of the steps in the first paragraph to no avail.

Comment: I honestly don't know what happened, but it is working now.  I flashed the firmware and followed the steps you laid out, taking into account what boot13 had to say.  It didn't work after a router reboot.  I tried back again a week later from work and there's my site.  Thanks so much both of you.  On the second issue, I was able to get the router seen upstairs by boosting Tx Power, but still couldn't connect.. same thing is happening with a Windows 7 laptop.. who knows..  I didn't have any of these issues before changing firmware.