# How to host a website on a wifi-router and a USB drive?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, router, dd-wrt

I have a TP-Link MR-3020 Router with a USB port.

What I want to do is to setup a website on my USB flash drive, which will be connected to the router via the USB port. Now, when anybody is connected to the router through wifi, when he goes to the router's IP address, instead of going to the firmware page, the user goes to the website on the USB stick.

Is this possible in any way?

I have read the following but they didn't help:

[DD-WRT Host IIS website](https://superuser.com/questions/318853/dd-wrt-host-iis-website)

[Can I set up a website on a wifi router?](https://superuser.com/questions/240946/can-i-set-up-a-website-on-a-wifi-router)

Comment: You won't be able to actually install IIS on a router for lots of reasons, the main reason, your router can't run Windows. ** What you want as described cannot be done.**

Comment: In what way did those links "Not help"?  The second one seems to answer your question to me.  What exactly have you tried already? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @Ramhound I am not looking at IIS. I don't like it. I would use PHP and Apache...

Comment: @techie007 The link you are talking about discusses about storing the website on the router itself or somewhere else. I want to store it on the usb drive connected to the router. This is because it will offer me more portability. The router is very small and I can power it with a portable battery. So I would keep the router, USB and the adapter in a bag, carrying it around.

Comment: @AwalGarg - Your router still cannot be the actual web server.

Comment: @AwalGarg If that's all you have to offer for the differences, then this _is_ a dupe, IMO. The question marked covers setting up a web server on a router, whether your router allows that, and whether it will additionally allow you to use the USB drive as a storage space is depends on your router. Go try things suggested there and come back with specific questions about specific problems regarding your specific setup.

Comment: @AwalGarg If you are wanting a cheap "portable webserver", why not either run one off an old Android cellphone/tablet or Raspberry PI or equivalent.  I'd imagine both of those would be easier to power up and carry with you.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this should be possible, but non-trivial, and doing it could brick your device.  You might want to look at loading [OpenWrt](http://openwrt.org/) (which appears to support your device but is harder to use then [DD-WRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DD-WRT)) onto your router, then configuring [Apache](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/http.apache).  (You may want to move the default port for any web interface you put on to manage OpenWrt to a another port to free up port 80).

I agree with @Ramhound that you can't install IIS on an embedded router, but IIS is only a webserver - Apache does a similar job, as do a [number of other web servers](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/hosting/list_of_web_servers.php3).

Comment: Would it run pages from the usb drive?

Comment: @AwalGarg - You can configure Apache to run from a USB drive on a normal computer.  I am not sure what good it would do though.

Comment: @Ramhound You mean, even if the computer is connected only through wifi?

Comment: @AwalGarg - No..I don't mean that in the slightest.  I mean exactly what I said.

Comment: @AwalGarg Yes, it should be able to be configured to run pages from the USB drive, presuming it was plugged in all the time or mounted in the same path.

Comment: @davidgo Yup, it will be always plugged in. But I am still stuck, I don't know how do I go about doing that?